# Input is cut off in text field after a random threshold

Tags: css

I try now for hours to find the reason for this. I have normal text in a text field. For texting purposes, I copied the lorem ipsum dummy text in it. So no special/escape characters at all, just normal text.

But as you can see on the screenshot the text is cut off in the middle of the line. I tried to align it differently, but the whole text still gets cut off. I tried for testing purposes to change the font size and the visible text varies, but never the full text. I don't have a clear indicator after how many characters or px the text is cut-off. It's quite random according to the font size.

I have checked the parameters in the style.css or bootstrap.min.css and also in WordPress itself and couldn't find any parameter that does some kind of input validation or limits the character input.

I hope anybody else has an idea what the reason can be or which parameters else to check.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I would assume a plugin or theme function is running a filter on post content and doing something incorrectly. Test another theme, if problem is still present start disabling plugins until the problem resolves.

Comment: it's a customized theme and I can't change it. Can it be some call routine in the functions.php?

Comment: So test disabling plugins instead and see if the problem resolves. If the issue remains, then start looking through the theme functions for anything hooked to `the_content`.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.